# How to disallow edits in layers on a QGIS project?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

So I'm adding layers to QGIS from Postgresql, is there a way to "lock" certain layers and make sure that users don't accidentally move stuff around or delete them?

Ideally something done on the project level would be ideal but if it can't be done then how to prevent it from the db?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new user in PostGIS and give only SELECT rights. By this way, users can't edit the layer.

Or, in the QGIS project properties, on Identify layers, check the layers to lock (read only). But users could deactivate this.

Comment: Thanks. We are changing DBs so and adding a bunch of users so we'll leave that until then. Have to wait a few mins to give you the green tick