# QGIS turn right click -- "Toggle Editing" off

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

In QGIS3, Interface customization I have turned off the mEditMenu but when a user right clicks on a dateset they still see "Toggle Editing".

Is it possible to remove this? and also any keyboard shortcuts that allow the same.

Comment: Also: Attribute table> Toggle editing. Layer properties> Fields> Toggle editing. You can make layers read only: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290748/how-to-disallow-edits-in-layers-on-a-qgis-project